# Python: getting type error when import function used

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a method as follows:

`def importFrom(module, name):
    module = importlib.import_module(module)
    return getattr(module, name)`

Then use it as follows:

`def imputation_LR (df, name): 
    reg = importFrom('sklearn.linear_model', name)
    reg.fit(X_train, y_train)`

Then call it as follows:

`data = imputation_LR (data, 'LinearRegression')`

and get the error below:
    `reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

I feel like this is about something `LinearRegression` / `LinearRegression()`, but couldn't figure out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `LinearRegression` object. The reason you get the error is because `fit` is an instance method (all of which pass `self` as the first parameter). So the function interface is really `fit(self, x, y)`. `self` is a special variable that is automatically passed in by an object reference upon invocation of an instance method. Try this (note I added `()`, see inline comment):

```
def imputation_LR (df, name): 
    reg = importFrom('sklearn.linear_model', name)() # Note I added () here
    reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Note that it's under the Methods section of the API documented here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html.

When in doubt, read the docs.

P.S. It's not totally clear why you're trying to import modules as a string. You can just import using the name of the package/module you want to grab:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression()
...
```

Comment: For P.S.: Yes, just importing the package is OK, but I want to pass the module name in importFrom('sklearn.linear_model', name), so that I can use Linear, Logistic, or some other regression models with imputation_LR (df, name). Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @alamaranka You could just pass the class instead of importing a new name.